# TYPO3 11.5.24-11.5.x + FLUX 9.7.2 no content render after update

Tags: typo3

After update, no one element shown on pages. Same for regular fluid styled content and FCE.
FLUX pages work fine, but no any content element shown.
My log:

- Upgrading doctrine/deprecations (v1.0.0 => v1.1.1)
- Upgrading guzzlehttp/guzzle (7.5.1 => 7.7.0)
- Upgrading guzzlehttp/promises (1.5.2 => 1.5.3)
- Upgrading nikic/php-parser (v4.15.4 => v4.16.0)
- Upgrading phpdocumentor/type-resolver (1.7.1 => 1.7.2)
- Upgrading phpstan/phpdoc-parser (1.20.4 => 1.22.1)
- Upgrading symfony/cache (v6.2.10 => v6.3.1)
- Upgrading symfony/cache-contracts (v3.2.1 => v3.3.0)
- Upgrading symfony/console (v5.4.23 => v5.4.24)
- Upgrading symfony/dependency-injection (v5.4.23 => v5.4.25)
- Upgrading symfony/deprecation-contracts (v3.2.1 => v3.3.0)
- Upgrading symfony/event-dispatcher (v6.2.8 => v6.3.0)
- Upgrading symfony/filesystem (v5.4.23 => v5.4.25)
- Upgrading symfony/http-foundation (v5.4.23 => v5.4.25)
- Upgrading symfony/lock (v6.2.8 => v6.3.1)
- Upgrading symfony/process (v6.2.10 => v6.3.0)
- Upgrading symfony/property-info (v5.4.23 => v5.4.24)
- Upgrading symfony/routing (v5.4.22 => v5.4.25)
- Upgrading symfony/string (v6.2.8 => v6.3.0)
- Upgrading symfony/var-exporter (v6.2.10 => v6.3.0)
- Upgrading typo3fluid/fluid (2.7.4 => 2.9.2)

All packages were downgraded but nothing help. Any idea or same situations?